#  searching in sorted Indexes of tuple list by bubble sort in haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

I choice binary search for index of array of record ascasestudy for my graduate research by c++ and haskell I **write** the c++ code and work and now I work for the haskell one

```
  import Data.List

  data BookInfo = Book Int String [String]
            deriving (Show)
```

--Entering the variables

```
  entering :: Int String [String]-> Book
  entering id name subject= Book id name subject
```

--make an idex of the array of tuples

```
  index :: [Book]->[Int]
  index [m] = getID (Book id _     _      ) = id
  main :: IO ()
  main = do
  putStrLn "Please enter your book id,name,Subject"
  Book inpStr <- getLine
  putStrLn print r
```

-- BubbleSort using map

```
 bubbleSort ::(Ord x) => [x] -> [x]
 bubbleSort (x':xs) = if x>x' then x': bubbleSort(x:xs)
                  else
                  if x<x' then x: bubbleSort(x':xs)
                  else 
                               x: bubbleSort(X':xs)

 bubble ::[a] -> [a]
 bubble [a] = map bubbleSort [a]
```

--Make index for the array

```
 indexsort(ord a)::[int]->[Int]
 indexsort a=bubble a
```

--Make the list of tuples

```
 addBooks2List Book->[Book]->[Book]
 addBooks2List b m=b:entering b':m
```

--binarysearch

```
 binarysearch [Int]->Int->Int->Int->Int
 a=bubble x
 binaryseach a i m j=
 let u=(i+m)/2
 if a[u]=j then u
 if a[u]>j then binaryseach a i u-1 j
 else 
 if a[u]<j then binarysearch a u+1 m j
 if i=m "Not found"
```

--printing the tuple that has the searched id

```
 print::Int->Book
 print r= Book r y z 
 r=binaryseach m 0 (length m)
```

it made an error at 8:3 parse error on input 'entering' what this error mean? and how I can correct it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, the type signature for `entering` should read

```
entering :: Int -> String -> [String] -> BookInfo
```

rather than `entering :: Int String [String]-> Book`—but that's a type error, not a parse error.

Perhaps your indentation is wrong, but that's hard to tell without having your code available verbatim. Remember: in Haskell, as opposed to languages such as C and Java, the layout of your code matters.

Anyway, the code, as you have posted it, is far from a working solution for your problem. You may want to take a few steps back and study how to write elementary functions in Haskell and then, later, how to glue them together in order to get at more involved programs. I really doubt whether learning the language by trying to convert snippets of C++ into Haskell has a high chance of success. Just my two cents, though...

Answer (score 3):

There are so many problems in your code, you best start with a single function and grow your program slowly and see that you get the incremental pieces compiled. Starting with this:

```
entering :: Int String [String]-> Book
entering id name subject= Book id name subject
```

First, `Book` is not a type but a data constructor, the type is `BookInfo`. Then, you're missing the arrows (as dblhelix pointed out). So it should read:

```
entering :: Int -> String -> [String]-> BookInfo
entering id name subject= Book id name subject
```

This will compile. However, `entering` now is just the same as `Book`. Anyway, continue with adding the next function and getting it compiled and so on.

If we go on,

```
index :: [Book]->[Int]
index [m] =
```

The definition is missing (what's on the right-hand side of `=`?), and `[m]` will only match a lists with a single element which is probably not what you want. Complete this function, or comment it out and continue with the rest. Apparently you don't use it at all currently. And so on.